# c# Create new SQLite file using praeclarum/sqlite-net package (SQLite-net PCL)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am have been searching for the best ORM for SQLite for my project and I have found [praeclarum/sqlite-net package](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

The problem I don't know how I might use this library to create an SQLite file if it does not exists in a directory. There is no documentation about this and I want to create the file in the user's My Documents folder. Here is my code so far.

```
private string databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "AttorneySpace\\database.db");
private SQLiteConnection db;

public SQLiteDb()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(databasePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(databasePath);
    }
    db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
    db.CreateTable<Stock>();
    db.CreateTable<Valuation>();
}
```

For this I get the exception;

```
An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite-net.dll but was not handled in user code
Could not open database file: ...AttorneySpace\database.db (CannotOpen)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create the file with `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection` although it is not part of the library that I am using;

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databasePath);
```